# why none output in list method?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nonetype

so where from "None" came in my output

```
a=[19,20,21]
print(a)
b=a.insert(1, 1907)
print(b)
```

when i write this code it give me this output

```
[19, 20, 21]
None
```

BUT the output should be

```
[19, 20, 21]
[19,1907,20,21]
```

so where from "None" came in my output

Comment: Does the documentation for `list.insert` mention any return value? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists